# Passing props from main class to drawer menu in React Navigation

Tags: react-navigation

I have a social RN project named "Cooked on your neighbourhood than you have a slice" for giving away food who in need of it at https://github.com/EnginYilmaz/kpbduser

I am using React Navigator for navigation and menus but I cannot figured out how to pass arguments from in my App.js (https://github.com/EnginYilmaz/kpbduser/blob/reactnavigation/App.js).

I want to pass argument because I want to show picture of the user on the Drawer menu.
[image]
I succeed in passing props from Main "App" class to "RootStack" but cannot figured out how to pass from "RootStack" to "DrawerMenu" and then from "DrawerMenu" to "customDrawerHeader" function.

Briefly my question that is on the diagram. What code I needed for each part of passing arguments.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing props to Custom Drawer Navigator in React Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580797/passing-props-to-custom-drawer-navigator-in-react-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but after long searching I see my question as a duplicate. What worked for me is [negative-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735864/negative-zero) 's answer: [Passing props to Custom Drawer Navigator in React Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580797/passing-props-to-custom-drawer-navigator-in-react-navigation)